# How to distinguish default argument and argument provided with default value?

Tags: python, default-arguments

Say I have function `f` as follows:

```py
def f(c=None):
    return 42 if c is None else c
```

Then I can't get `None` out of this function. Now you could think "well, just check for another value like `2128.213` or whatever" but then I can't get that specific value out of the function can I?

That's why I'd like to distinguish, if possible, between `f()` and `f(None)` so that I can have

```
f() -> 42
f(None)-> None
```

Bear in mind this is a simplified example. In practice it's a class's `__init__(...)` function with multiple positional arguments which I'd like to handle as `c` in this example.

Comment: why do you need to know if None comes from here or there? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What woudl you like to do differently if `f()` vs. `f(None)`?

Comment: incorrect logic even if your c is none you will still get 42

Comment: Wait, do you want to distinguish between a None from the definition and a None the user passed ?

Comment: Use a a default value something like `_DEFAULT = object()`, defined in the same module - no other module can possibly pass a value that's identical to that.

Comment: yes @Programmer! Indeed :)

Comment: @jasonharell lol, was going to tell the OP the same if he confirmed my question ...

Comment: I don't understand the down vote but Ok I guess ; @Programmer @jasonharper you mean I can't right? There's no buiilt-in way to distinguish and so having a module-level object with a unique `id()` will allow me to circumvent this, right?

Comment: @ted me neither, wasn't me ...

Comment: Related: [Sentinel object and its applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39313943/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common practice in such cases is to use specific sentinel value you never want to return.

```
class Sentinel():
    pass


_sentinel = Sentinel()

# _sentinel = object()  # this is the option too

def f(x=_sentinel):
    return 42 if x is _sentinel else x

assert f() == 42
assert f(None) is None
assert f(5) == 5
```

Comment: @wjandrea `somemodule.f(somemodule._sentinel) == somemodule._sentinel`, that's the problem

Comment: @Programmer No one should use `somemodule._sentinel` because the leading underscore indicates that it's for internal use only. It's still possible of course, since Python doesn't have truly private variables, but it's strongly discouraged.

Comment: @wjandrea : please see  this comment and what they are discussing "Use a a default value something like _DEFAULT = object(), defined in the same module - no other module can possibly pass a value that's identical to that. – jasonharper"

Comment: Minor point: `assert f(None) == None` should be `assert f(None) is None`

Comment: @wjandrea "since Python doesn't have truly private variables" - it has, put `class cls: __attr = 1` in a py file, import it and try `print(somemodule.cls.__attr)` ...

Comment: @Diwakar Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Programmer That's still not truly private, just obfuscated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32802486/4518341) for an explanation. TL;DR `cls._cls__attr` is the obfuscated name.

Comment: @Programmer never heard about name mangling?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs obviously not, may you share a link ?

Comment: @wjandrea but it's as if it were private because you cannot access it

Comment: @Programmer You **can** access it, using `cls._cls__attr`. See the answer I linked for an explanation, as well as [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea thanks, I didn't know that, learned something new !

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Python's private attributes : Assign a new object to that private attribute, compare if the argument is the private object, and done.

```py
class somename:
    __default = object()
    def __init__(self, default=__default):
        print(42 if default is self.__default else default)

somename()
somename(default=12)
```

Comment: I often name it NULL to indicate "nothing specified".