# Count how many arguments passed as positional

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

If I have a function

```py
def foo(x, y):
    pass
```

how can I tell, from inside the function, whether `y` was passed positionally or with its keyword?

I'd like to have something like

```py
def foo(x, y):
    if passed_positionally(y):
        print('y was passed positionally!')
    else:
        print('y was passed with its keyword')
```

so that I get

```py
>>> foo(3, 4)
y was passed positionally
>>> foo(3, y=4)
y was passed with its keyword
```

---

I realise I didn't originally specify this, but is it possible to do this whilst preserving type annotations? The top answer so far suggests using a decorator - however, that does not preserve the return type

Comment: Interesting question, but what would be the use-case for such a feature? Why would a function treat an argument differently based on how it was passed?

Comment: Making this possible would allow different behaviors of a function wether you call it with `f(a, b)` or with `f(x=a, y=b)`, breaking the "contract" assumed by python function def: however you call it, if arguments are the same, the function should apply the same operations to the args.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the question. The title asks about a count of positional arguments. What does that have to do with determining whether `y` was passed positionally or by keyword?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is `def foo(*x, y=None):`?

Comment: I think you should either tag this with `[language-lawyer]` or state a *practical* need for this.

Comment: Practical need is to issue a deprecation warning for a library

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can create a decorator, like this:

```
def checkargs(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'y' in kwargs:
            print('y passed with its keyword!')
        else:
            print('y passed positionally.')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return inner

>>>  @checkargs
...: def foo(x, y):
...:     return x + y

>>> foo(2, 3)
y passed positionally.
5

>>> foo(2, y=3)
y passed with its keyword!
5
```

Of course you can improve this by allowing the decorator to accept arguments. Thus you can pass the parameter you want to check for. Which would be something like this:

```
def checkargs(param_to_check):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if param_to_check in kwargs:
                print('y passed with its keyword!')
            else:
                print('y passed positionally.')
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return inner

>>>  @checkargs(param_to_check='y')
...: def foo(x, y):
...:     return x + y

>>> foo(2, y=3)
y passed with its keyword!
5
```

I think adding [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) would preserve the annotations, following version also allows to perform the check over all arguments (using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)):

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def checkargs(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        for param in signature(func).parameters:
            if param in kwargs:
                print(param, 'passed with its keyword!')
            else:
                print(param, 'passed positionally.')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return inner

>>>  @checkargs
...: def foo(x, y, z) -> int:
...:     return x + y

>>> foo(2, 3, z=4)
x passed positionally.
y passed positionally.
z passed with its keyword!
9

>>> inspect.getfullargspec(foo)
FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, 
kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={'return': <class 'int'>})
                                             _____________HERE____________
```

---

## **Update** [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)

In Python 3.10+ new [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) type annotation was introduced ([PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#concatenating-keyword-parameters)), for better specifying parameter types in higher-order functions. As of now, the correct way to annotate this decorator would be like this:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


def check_args(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    """
    Decorator to monitor whether an argument is passed
    positionally or with its keyword, during function call.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        for param in signature(func).parameters:
            if param in kwargs:
                print(param, 'passed with its keyword!')
            else:
                print(param, 'passed positionally.')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner
```

Which correctly preserves type annotation:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(foo(2, 3))

# ─❯ mypy check_kwd.py
# check_kwd.py:34: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
# Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't preserve type annotations though - e.g. if I put `def foo(x, y) -> int` and then do `reveal_type(foo(2, y=3))`, I get `Any`

Comment: Actually the answer is no! there isn't anyway to tell. you turned the function into another function that takes `*args` and `**kwargs` . btw I am upvoter.

Comment: Thanks @Cyttorak - I tried that, but `reveal_type(foo(2, 3))` still shows `Any`, while if I remove the decorator it shows `builtins.int`

Answer (score 14):

At the end, if you are going to do something like this:

```
def foo(x, y):
    if passed_positionally(y):
        raise Exception("You need to pass 'y' as a keyword argument")
    else:
        process(x, y)
```

You can do this:

```
def foo(x, *, y):
    pass

>>> foo(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

>>> foo(1, y=2) # works
```

Or only allow them to be passed positionally:

```
def foo(x, y, /):
    pass

>>> foo(x=1, y=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'x, y'

>>> foo(1, 2) # works
```

See [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) and [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for more.

Answer (score 5):

Adapted from @Cyttorak 's answer, here's a way to do it which maintains the types:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any, TYPE_CHECKING

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Callable[..., Any])

from functools import wraps
import inspect

def checkargs() -> Callable[[T], T]:
    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            for param in inspect.signature(func).parameters:
                if param in kwargs:
                    print(param, 'passed with its keyword!')
                else:
                    print(param, 'passed positionally.')
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return inner
    return decorate

@checkargs()
def foo(x, y) -> int:
    return x+y

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(foo(2, 3))
foo(2, 3)
foo(2, y=3)
```

Output is:

```
$ mypy t.py 
t.py:27: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```

```
$ python t.py 
x passed positionally.
y passed positionally.
x passed positionally.
y passed with its keyword!
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not ordinarily possible. In a sense: the language is not designed to allow you to distinguish both ways.

You can design your function to take different parameters - positional, and named, and check which one was passed, in a thing like:

```
def foo(x, y=None, /, **kwargs):
 
    if y is None: 
        y = kwargs.pop(y)
        received_as_positional = False
    else:
        received_as_positional = True
```

The problem is that, although by using positional only parameters as abov, you could get `y` both ways,
it would be shown not once for a user (or IDE) inspecting the
function signature.

I hav a feeling you just want to know this for the sake of knowing - if
you really intend this for design of an API, I'd suggest you'd rethink
your API - there should be no difference in the behavior, unless both
are un-ambiguously different parameters from the user point of view.

That said, the way to go would be to inspect the caller frame, and check
the bytecode around the place the function is called:

```py
In [24]: import sys, dis

In [25]: def foo(x, y=None):
    ...:     f = sys._getframe().f_back
    ...:     print(dis.dis(f.f_code))
    ...: 

In [26]: foo(1, 2)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 PRINT_EXPR
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
None

In [27]: foo(1, y=2)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (('y',))
              8 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
             10 PRINT_EXPR
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, as you can see, when `y` is called as named parameter, the opcode for the call is `CALL_FUNCTION_KW` , and the name of the parameter is loaded into the stack imediately before it.

Comment: My use-case is to put in a deprecation warning so I can make an argument keyword-only in a future release

Comment: I guess the first approach here would work them. If you prefer going the decorator way, I have a way to create a decorator that would preserve the typehints and signature (which I could factor out to an opensource package) - let me know.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You can trick the user and add another argument to the function like this:

```
def foo(x,y1=None,y=None):
  if y1 is not None:
    print('y was passed positionally!')
  else:
    print('y was passed with its keyword')
```

I don't recommend doing it but it does work

Comment: I don't think this would work. I could run `foo(None, None, None)` or `foo(None, y=None)`

Comment: Thats why I said you can trick the user, if only 2 arguments are passed than it would work. As long as you don't pass None to y1 and if you want to keep it an option u can use a dummy value that will never be used

Comment: You could use a sentinel (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313943/sentinel-object-and-its-applications) rather than `None` to guard against `foo(None, None)`

Answer (score 3):

In `foo`, you can pass the call stack from `traceback` to `positionally`, which will then parse the lines, find the line where `foo` itself is called, and then parse the line with `ast` to locate positional parameter specifications (if any):

```
import traceback, ast, re
def get_fun(name, ast_obj):
    if isinstance(ast_obj, ast.Call) and ast_obj.func.id == name:
        yield from [i.arg for i in getattr(ast_obj, 'keywords', [])]
    for a, b in getattr(ast_obj, '__dict__', {}).items():
        yield from (get_fun(name, b) if not isinstance(b, list) else \
                        [i for k in b for i in get_fun(name, k)])

def passed_positionally(stack):
    *_, [_, co], [trace, _] = [re.split('\n\s+', i.strip()) for i in stack] 
    f_name = re.findall('(?:line \d+, in )(\w+)', trace)[0]
    return list(get_fun(f_name, ast.parse(co)))

def foo(x, y):
    if 'y' in passed_positionally(traceback.format_stack()):
        print('y was passed with its keyword')
    else:
        print('y was passed positionally')

foo(1, y=2)
```

Output:

```
y was passed with its keyword
```

Notes:

1. This solution does not require any wrapping of `foo`. Only the traceback needs to be captured.
2. To get the full `foo` call as a string in the traceback, this solution must be run in a file, not the shell.

Comment: To do this kind of magic reliably, specifically obtaining the AST node, use https://github.com/alexmojaki/executing